# Use Js value in CSS

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, css

I have the URL of an image I'd like to set as background of a div, but I don't know how to do that.

I'm using a @wire method to retrieve name, description and this URL from an obj in Salesforce, so it's saved on a JS variable.

How do I refer that variable in my css?

I tried using inline css like:

```
<div style={headerURL}></div>
```

where headerURL is:

```
get headerURL() {
    return this.obj.headerImageURL;
}
```

but it gives me an error in VScode and also it's not working.

Any idea of how to solve this?

Comment: I think you should put img tag inside a div to add an image something like below : 
<div class="someClass">
            <img src={headerURL}>
        </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using style. Set the style in JS like below.

```
get headerURL() {
    return `background-image: url("${this.obj.headerImageURL}");`;
}
```

HTML

```
<div style={headerURL}></div>
```

Comment: It works! Thanks! Any idea how to get rid of the warnings that vscode gives like "} expected"?

Comment: @FrancescoGhiselli You can ignore that, or use an alternative way of manipulating style using template query selector and JS code from controller.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll look into the query selector method thanks!